# db2 suppress recursive warning

Tags: sql, db2

I have a recursive sql that I am running which works but gives me the following warning.

SQL0347W  The recursive common table expression "DT_LAST_YEAR" may 
contain an infinite loop.  SQLSTATE=01605

How can I get rid of the warning?

```
INSERT INTO REP_MAN_TRAN_COUNTS (SITEDIRECTORYID, BUSINESSDATE, TRANCOUNT)
WITH dt_this_year (level, seqdate) AS  
( 
   SELECT 1, date(current timestamp) -7 DAYS FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT level, seqdate + level days FROM dt_this_year WHERE level < 1000 AND seqdate + 1 days < date(current timestamp) 
) 
,dt_last_year (level, seqdate) AS  
( 
   SELECT 1, date(current timestamp) -7 DAYS - 1 year FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT level, seqdate + level days FROM dt_last_year WHERE level < 1000 AND seqdate + 1 days < date(current timestamp) -1 year 
) 
select 10049, date(dts.calendarday), count(*) trancount 
from (
   SELECT seqdate AS calendarday FROM dt_this_year  
   UNION 
   SELECT seqdate AS calendarday FROM dt_last_year
) dts LEFT JOIN ccftrxheader ccf 
ON date(dts.calendarday) = date(ccf.businessdate) 
WHERE ccf.sitedirectoryid=10049 
GROUP BY ccf.sitedirectoryid,dts.calendarday
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you get rid of warnings?
By changing the code so that it no longer generates the warning in the first place.  *Hiding* warnings is problematic, because it often disguises a potentially larger problem.  I'm fairly certain it's complaining here because the termination clause you provide for `level` can't ever be reached (because you never manipulate it).

Personally, I'd probably re-write your query into something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Rep_Man_Tran_Counts (siteDirectoryId, businessDate, tranCount)

WITH dt_Calendar_Data (level, calendarDay) AS
                      (SELECT l, c
                       FROM (VALUES (1, CURRENT_DATE - 7 DAYS),
                                    (1, CURRENT_DATE - 7 DAYS - 1 YEAR)) t(l, c)
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT level + 1, calendarDay + 1 DAYS
                       FROM dt_Calendar_Data
                       WHERE level < 7)
SELECT 10049, dtCal.calendarDay, COALESCE(COUNT(*), 0) as tranCount
FROM dt_Calendar_Data dtCal
LEFT JOIN ccftrxHeader ccf
       ON ccf.businessDate = dtCal.calendarDay
          AND ccf.siteDirectoryId = 10049

GROUP BY dtCal.seqDate
```

(untested, as you've provided no sample data, and I don't have a DB2 instance)
I've assumed you actually wanted a `LEFT JOIN`, as opposed to the regular `INNER JOIN` you were actually getting (due to the condition in the `WHERE` clause, and probably the `GROUP BY` as well).  To avoid adding nulls to your data, I've wrapped the count in `COALESCE(...)`, which will give you `0` instead.
I've also assumed that `businessDate` is a `DATE` type, and not a timestamp.  If it *is* a timestamp this query needs to be adjusted (note that the function you were using would for the optimizer to ignore indices).
Note that order of operations with dates matter!  Thankfully when dealing with year ranges, you only have one day to worry about in the Gregorian calendar (February 29th).  Your current ordering will compare identical calendar days at the *start* of the range (which one has the "gap" depends on whether this year or last year is a leap year).

---

## EDIT:

Sure, lets look at that CTE:

```
FROM(VALUES (1, CURRENT_DATE - 7 DAYS),
            (1, CURRENT_DATE - 7 DAYS - 1 YEAR)) t(l, c)
```

This is just a standard `VALUES` clause used as a table reference.  This is the SQL Standard way to construct a small temp table (Rather than referencing the dummy tables, which tend to be vendor-specific).  If the statement is run on `2014-02-26` then the resulting table will be:

```
t
l  c
===============
1  "2014-02-19"
1  "2013-02-19"
```

These columns get renamed by the column listing of the CTE, which are then referenced in the join (and in the case of a recursive CTE, by the recursive portion).
This then forms the starting data for the rest of the recursive query:

```
 UNION ALL
 SELECT level + 1, calendarDay + 1 DAYS
 FROM dt_Calendar_Data
 WHERE level < 7
```

In DB2 (and some other RDBMSs), recursive CTEs essentially execute iteratively, acting off the results of the "previous" invocation.  Every time around, we increment `level`, and add another day to `calendarDay`.  The "next" rows are then:

```
level  calendarDay
======================
2      "2014-02-20"
2      "2013-02-20"
```

This continues until the "previous" row has `level = 7`, which means a new row is not generated (check the `WHERE` clause).  In general, it's best to only have one termination condition (and make progress every iteration), to make it easier for the optimizer to spot.  The resulting data is then in the ranges:

```
level  calendarDay
=====================
1      "2014-02-19"
.      .....
7      "2014-02-26"

1      "2013-02-19"
.      .....
7      "2013-02-26"
```

... as a side note, I generated the this year/last year data together to make the number of references shorter.  If you only needed the one year, `level` is unnecessary.

Comment: wow.. thanks.. that was brilliant. I made some slight mods to what you gave me and it worked exactly the way I wanted it to. Sorry to bug you but can you do me a favor and what you have put in the with clause. I am having troubles understanding how the recursion works.

Comment: @Richie - something like this?